# Distinct values of bitwise and of subarrays

Tags: algorithm

How to find number of distinct values of bitwise and of all subarrays of an array.(Array size <=1e5 and array elements<=1e6).
for eg.
A[]={1,2,3}
distinct values are 4(1,2,3,0).

Comment: i have tried a lot could you please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's fix the right boundary `r` of the subarray. Let's image the left boundary `l` moves to the left starting from `r`. How many times can the value of the `and` change? At most `O(log(MAX_VALUE))`. Why? When we add one more element to the left, we've got two options:

1. The `and` value of the subarray doesn't change.
2. It changes. In that case, the number of bits in it gets strictly less (as it's a submask of the previous `and` value).

Thus, we can consider only those values of `l` where something changes. Now we just need to find them quickly.

Let's iterate over the array from left to right and store the position of the last element that doesn't have the `i`-th bit for all valid `i` (we can update it by iterating over all bits of the current element). This way, we'll be able to find the next position where the value changes quickly (namely, it's the largest value in this array over all bits that are set). If we sort the positions, we can find the next largest one in `O(1)`.

The total time complexity of this solution is `O(N * log(MAX_VALUE) * log(log(MAX_VALUE)))` (we iterate over all bits of each element of the array, we sort the array of positions for each them and iterate over it). The space complexity is `O(N + MAX_VALUE)`. It should be good enough for the given contraints.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How does your method avoid duplicate counts for something like this: `[1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4]` ?

Comment: could you please elaborate with help of an example.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Duplicate counts don't matter (we can store the masks we've seen in a boolean array).

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the numbers as columns representing their bits. We will have sequences of 1's extending horizontally. For example:

```
Array index:  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7

Bit columns:  0  1  1  1  1  1  0  0
              0  0  0  1  1  1  1  1
              0  0  1  1  1  1  1  0
              1  0  0  0  1  1  0  1
              0  1  1  1  1  1  1  0
```

Looking to the left, the bit-row for any subarray `and`ed after a zero will continue being zero, which means no change after that in that row.

Let's take index 5 for example. Now sorting the horizontal sequences of 1's from index 5 to the left will provide us a simple way to detect a change in the bit configuration (the sorting would have to be done on each iteration):

```
                        Index 5 ->
Sorted bit rows:  1  0  0  0  1  1
                  0  0  0  1  1  1
                  0  0  1  1  1  1
                  0  1  1  1  1  1
                  0  1  1  1  1  1

  Index 5 to 4, no change
  Index 4 to 3, change
  Index 2 to 1, change
  Index 1 to 0, change
```

To easily examine these changes, kraskevich proposes recording only the last unset bit for each row as we go along, which would indicate the length of the horizontal sequence of 1's, and a boolean array (of `1e6` numbers max) to store the unique bit configurations encountered.

```
Numbers: 1,  2,  3

Bits:    1   0   1
         0   1   1
```

As we move from left to right, keep a record of the index of the last unset bit in each row, and also keep a record of any new bit configuration (at most `1e6` of them):

```
Indexes of last unset bit for each row on each iteration
Numbers: 1,  2,  3

A[0]:   -1        arrayHash = [false,true,false,false], count = 1
         0

A[1]:   -1   1    Now sort the column descending, representing (current - index)
         0   0     the lengths of sequences of 1's extending to the left.

As we move from top to bottom on this column, each value change represents a bit
configuration and a possibly distinct count:

  Record present bit configuration b10
    => arrayHash = [false,true,true,false]

  1 => 1 - 1 => sequence length 0, ignore sequence length 0
  0 => 1 - 0 => sequence length 1,
                  unset second bit: b10 => b00 
                  => new bit configuration b00
                  => arrayHash = [true,true,true,false]
```

Third iteration:

```
Numbers: 1,  2,  3

A[2]:   -1   1   1
         0   0   0

Record present bit configuration b11
    => arrayHash = [true,true,true,true]
```

(We continue since we don't necessarily know the arrayHash has filled.)

```
  1 => 2 - 1 => sequence length 1
                  unset first bit: b11 => b10
                  => seen bit configuration b10
  0 => 2 - 0 => sequence length 2,
                  unset second bit: b10 => b00 
                  => seen bit configuration b00
```